# Viewing Gigapixel Images

Tags: image-processing, imaging, deepzoom

I am processing gigapixel images and want to display them.I have the subimages at different levels of the image pyramid.Now I need a viewer which can be used to show these images in the output? I looked at deep zoom and indeed my output is like the one wanted by it but I do not want to use deep zoom composer .I want to directly link the subsampled images that I create with the viewer.Is it possible to do so and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing, but maybe [Nip2](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Nip2) can help?

Comment: Thanks for reply.May i know What is it that you are not sure of?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your deepzoom image in .dzi format, this will help. Download the openseadragon folder from https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/releases/download/v2.3.1/openseadragon-bin-2.3.1.zip.

Copy script from https://openseadragon.github.io/docs/ and give correct path of image directory and openseadragon folder and save it in .HTML to view the .dzi image from browser. You can write your own code to automatically link the image path and openseadragon js folder if you need. Hope this help.